# Start Intent after click on Push Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification

Well, I'm working on a push notification feature. It starts the intent just after it receives the push message. But I'd like to start the intent after the user click on the notification.

So, how could I do that? How could I detect the user click on the message received?

Below the code that I wrote:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("ALERT", "Message Received");

    Intent screen2 = new Intent(context, Tela2.class);
    screen2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(screen2);
}
```

It's working Ok

Answer (score 0):

You should create and display a notification, and use a pending intent to specify which activity to start from the notification.

For example :

```
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, Tela2.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
    .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

That code would start the activity when the notification is clicked.

Comment: Thanks, let me try it!